# Binding click to a function residing in a different (but included first) file

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page starts out with a disabled button, having no click handler. Later on, when some changes have been made, the button will be enabled. Just to clarify, I included File A before File B in my layout.

My current setup is this:

**File A**

```
function enableButton() {
    $("#Accept").on("click", clickAccept);
}

function clickAccept() {
    // do stuff
}
```

**File B** (inside another function)

```
enableButton();
```

This works as intended. However, while I was moving some stuff around, I tried the following:

**File A**

```
function clickAccept() {
    // do stuff
}
```

**File B** (inside another function)

```
$("#Accept").on("click", clickAccept);
```

Whenever I click the button, it will trigger an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in jquery.min.js. When I call the function `clickAccept()` from the console, it will execute without error.

This leads me to believe that the actual binding didn't go right. It seems a bit strange, I thought, as long as the JavaScript files are included, it doesn't matter that they're technically in different files. Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

should be like this:

```
function enableButton() {
    $("#Accept").on("click", function(){
        clickAccept();
    });
}
```

should be wrapped in a function, and called as a function

Comment: The first situation actually works; it's the second situation that came up with the behavior described.

Comment: then try to make sure file A is loaded before file B
and even better make sure you add the eventlistener after body load event:
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#Accept").on("click", clickAccept);});

Comment: Yes, I'm inclined to agree with tripleb. You're probably trying to attach a click handler to an DOM element that does not exist yet as the DOM is not fully loaded until the 'document ready' event has fired.
See here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: That's the funny thing about it - File A is definitely loaded before File B (as observed in the page source), and the attaching only happens after I save changes I'm making in a Kendo Grid control. Furthermore, almost the exact same thing happens in the first situation, excepting that I call a function that handles the attaching, rather than doing it explicitly.

Comment: yes that is the point probably, hard to say without seeing the project but my guess is you are attaching the click event before you have the element in the dome that is why you sould wait for the dom to be ready